# Ocelot reverse proxy - Two requests at same time (For different users) returns the same data

Tags: .net-core, microservices, reverse-proxy, ocelot

I have a microservice application that's using NetCore API and Ocelot as reverse proxy. I'm having the following issue:

- When two users log into my application they're redirected a page where the request /api/Dashboard loads the data if those user log at the same second it will duplicate the response for them. My request does not have anything else to identify the users but the headers - where the token is different for each user.
- If the user who gets the duplicated data reloads his page, the data will come up right.

My guess is that it has todo either with Ocelot - behaving as a FirstIn-FirstOut or the structure of my API that will need some id to identify the session or request?

Dunno, I haven't been able to replicate this with Postman looks like it's happening when my app is published

Appreciate your comments and help. I know I don't have a perfect project architecture, so be  mindful I'm learning still.

Tried with postman - works fine. I'm expecting each user to get its data without getting overlapped by similar requests.